# SwiftUI NavigationLink not working in Simulator

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, xcode14

I'm following Apple's app dev Scrumdinger tutorial and I ran into an issue in the "Creating a navigation hierarchy" section. When I use the ForEach loop to iterate through the DailyScrum array and make a navigation link for each piece of data, the link works in the preview but not in the simulator.

This is the code with the ForEach loop:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScrumsView: View {
    let scrums: [DailyScrum]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(scrums) { scrum in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(scrum: scrum)) {
                    CardView(scrum: scrum)
                }
                .listRowBackground(scrum.theme.mainColor)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Daily Scrums")
        .toolbar {
            //this button will have an action later
            Button(action: {}) {   
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }
            .accessibilityLabel("New Scrum")
        }
    }
}

struct ScrumsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrumsView(scrums: DailyScrum.sampleData)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code where I defined the DailyScrum array:

```
import Foundation

struct DailyScrum: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var title: String
    var attendees: [Attendee]
    var lengthInMinutes: Int
    var theme: Theme
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), title: String, attendees: [String], lengthInMinutes: Int, theme: Theme) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.attendees = attendees.map{ Attendee(name: $0)}
        self.lengthInMinutes = lengthInMinutes
        self.theme = theme
    }
}

extension DailyScrum {
    struct Attendee: Identifiable {
        let id: UUID
        var name: String
        
        init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String) {
            self.id = id
            self.name = name
        }
    }
}

extension DailyScrum {
    static let sampleData: [DailyScrum] =
    [
        DailyScrum(title: "Design", attendees: ["Cathy", "Daisy", "Simon", "Jonathan"], lengthInMinutes: 10, theme: .yellow),
        DailyScrum(title: "App Dev", attendees: ["Katie", "Gray", "Euna", "Luis", "Darla"], lengthInMinutes: 5, theme: .orange),
        DailyScrum(title: "Web Dev", attendees: ["Chella", "Chris", "Christina", "Eden", "Karla", "Lindsey", "Aga", "Chad", "Jenn", "Sarah"], lengthInMinutes: 5, theme: .poppy)
    ]
}
```

The NavLink works as expected in the preview screen but it doesn't work when I run the simulator. Each scrum is greyed out and I can't click on anything.

Comment: The preview use a navigationView that you have forgotten in your parent view.

Comment: NavigationView is deprecated on iOS 16, seems Apple hasn't updated their tutorial

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Do not forget to embed the ScrumsView into a NavigationView

Comment: Code should be included as code not an image